# Copy nodes from a .sks file

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So what i try to do is what you can see at min. 8 in the famous "608 best practices for building spritekit games", but in Swift language.
Basically copy the children nodes from a SKScene that's within another .sks file.

I just managed to do it, in some way... But the program stops at a sort of automatic breakpoint with this message "Swift dynamic cast failed". I don't know what's wrong... I mean, i know the line, but i don't understand how the copy() method works.

Here's my code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

var camera = SKNode()
var player = SKNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    camera = childNodeWithName("Camera")! as SKNode
    player = camera.childNodeWithName("player")! as SKNode

    var child = SKNode()
    for child in SKScene.unarchiveFromFile("Player")!.children {
//Here is the line i doubt of
        player.addChild(child.copy() as SKNode)
    }
}

//etc etc...
```

Many thanks in advance :D

**EDIT:**
Yeah i created another project just to try this method and yep it still stops at that breakpoint. No errors, just stops there after i press run.

There is something wrong with this code...

```
var nodeToFill = SKNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    nodeToFill = childNodeWithName("nodeToFill")!

    var child = SKNode()
    for child in SKScene.unarchiveFromFile("fillNode")!.children {
        child.removeFromParent()
        nodeToFill.addChild(child as SKSpriteNode)
    }
```

and this is where it stops...
(can't post images...)
http: //i.stack.imgur.com/m6RRg.png

**EDIT 2:**
Okay so i put log and stack frame not as text to avoid making the page too long... Here they are:

Log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP7JP.png
Stack: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JReFU.png

The line where it stops is where the unarchiveFromFile method is called. It has something to do with that method but i can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: you can copy and paste the image as text (select & copy), but its contents are not relevant. call stack, log, and the line of code where the error occurs would be helpful.

Comment: also, copying the nodes is unnecessary if the sks scene is thrown away afterwards. Instead for every node you can/should call its removeFromParent method, then add it as child but without copying it

Comment: Hope i added the right things! Not so familiar with those logs and stack frames... not at all :/ Anyway the code is the one in the first edit. It doesn't change much though...

Comment: like I said, you can select that as text and paste it as text in the question, no need to make images

Comment: Have you tried to simply do: nodeToFill.addChild(SKSCene.unarchiveFromFile("fillNode"))

Comment: Sorry for the images, but that way the post does not become too long? However, i solved it! Thank you for your suggestion anyway :D

Comment: Links break, it's better to paste text in the question. Narrow it down to relevant parts if it's too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.
I just have to replace 
`for child in SKScene.unarchiveFromFile("fillNode")!.children` with `for child in GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("fillNode")!.children`.
Just replace "SKScene" with "GameScene"